# Как научиться составлять циклы/алгоритмы для своих задач?

Tags: алгоритм

Бывают замудренные задачи, и на такую задачу требуется составить цикл/алгоритм, начав пробовать ни к чему не прихожу, пишу на ХешКод, сразу помогают. Как придти к тому, чтобы я мог сам составлять алгоритмы? Как вы пришли к этому?

Comment: Научись для начал рисовать алгоритмы на бумаге, а не сразу падать в код. Мне это помогает, особенно, когда алгоритмы уже не вмещаются на лист формата A0 :)

Comment: ключ к успеху: алгоритмизация + абстракция + обобщение  

придти к этому можно 1 способом: теория + практика. качество и скорость прогресса будет зависить от идеального баланса этих 2х компонентов для вашего восприятия.  

я бы посоветовал прочитать (хотя бы начать читать) книжку по алгоритмам + реализация простых алгоритмов, напр: разные типы сортировок, работа со строками (попробуйте реализовать все функции доступные в классе стринг). попробуйте реализовать структуры: очередь, стек, лист (1-2 направленные)

Answer (score 18):

Четко разбейте задачу на составные части. Например Сходить_в_магазин включает в себя Одеться, Дойти до магазина, Купить необходимое, Вернуться, Раздеться. В свою очередь одеться можно разделить на одеть шапку, ботинки, фуфайку.
Более сложные задачи упрощайте до тех пор, пока они не превратятся в конкретные функции, операторы языка.
Поставьте четкую и определенную цель, что должна делать программа. Определите, какие данные она должна получить и какие данные нужно вернуть.
Это кратко. Более подробную информацию читайте [здесь](https://www.google.ru/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=asc2#hl=ru&newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2&oq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.12...0l0l3l9814l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0.frgbld.&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=819752767e1f19b1&biw=1366&bih=656) и [здесь](http://www.chemisk.narod.ru/html/algoritm01.html)

Answer (score 9):

Следуйте совету Дональда Кнута: читайте поваренные книги. Без шуток.

Comment: а что это?

Answer (score 6):

Для начала следует уяснить, что все давно придумали до вас, и не надо изобретать велосипед.
При изучении алгоритмов необходимо начинать с самых основ, а именно:
существует 3 (ТРИ) типа алгоритмов:

1. Линейный
2. Разветвляющийся
3. Циклический

А все велосипеды уже изобретаются на основе этих трех типов, и получаются смешанные алгоритмы, содержащие несколько других алгоритмов.

**Линейный** - алгоритм, в котором все команды выполняются последовательно, одна за другой.
**Разветвляющийся** - алгоритм, в котором та или иная команда реализуется в зависимости от выполнения некоторого условия.
**Циклический** - алгоритм, в котором серия команд выполняется многократно.

В интернетах полно информации на данную тему, в том числе:
 1. Как правильно смешивать алгоритмы
 2. Как правильно изображать алгоритмы на бумаге (по началу лучше делать именно так, а потом уже наберетесь опыта, научитесь в голове обрабатывать каждую процедуру, представляя картину в целом)

Дальше, как говорил товарищ [[@ReinRaus](/users/481/reinraus)](/users/481/reinraus), берете задачу, делаете декомпозицию (разбиваете на составляющие части), и представляете последовательность и условия взаимодействия частей. Нас учили на самых простых задачах, например: найти минимальное/максимальное из трёх чисел. Когда разберетесь с элементарщиной, можно приступать к чему-то более глобальному.